# c# code to control swf file

Tags: c#, asp.net, flash

how to control .swf file from c#. I was developed one asp page which contains flash file.  Is there any possibility to play and pause that flash file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

C# code is executed server-side. Flash animations are executed client-side.

Your best bet would be to see what you can accomplish with JavaScript.

Comment: thanks.I am trying to work on javascript but failed. Following is the code.

Comment: var flashMovie=getFlashMovieObject("flash.swf");
flashMovie.Stop();

Comment: @hemanth - getFlashMovieObject takes the name from the name attribute you assign in the markup, not the file name.